# How to fill background image with a flexbox div

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a div I want to fill entirely with a background image. The salmon color should be not be shown. How do I get this image to "zoom to fit"? I've tried various methods such as background-size: 100% 100% and flexbox.

https://codepen.io/2spacemilk/pen/zYKWLyM

```css
.this-div {
  background-color: salmon;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/6aRX4Hh.png');
  background-size: cover;
}
.payment-methods-strip {
  background-color: #fff;
  max-width: 438px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Can you close the div tag and specify the div height in pixels?

Comment: @Muhammad.fatiu ok updated

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be that your background image has transparent space on its top. Thus, the image *is* being displayed, it's just being pushed down by the extra invisible space. Could you try removing the extra space from the image (using an image editor)? If not, you can try to use `background-position` to manually position it to the top.

Comment: Interesting. How can you tell there is transparency? When I view it on Imgur and even on my computer I don't see that.

Comment: @Mark I just looked at the image at the URL specified in the CodePen: https://i.imgur.com/6aRX4Hh.png. You can see pretty clearly from the browser that there is extra space.

Comment: Yeah but how can you tell there's transparency at the top? When I view it on my computer I believe there is a checkered pattern I should see if there is any but I don't

Comment: @Mark Well, the browser automatically fills the transparency in with a background color (instead of using the traditional checkered pattern), but if you view it in any decent image editor (I'm using the default Ubuntu image viewer), then you should see the checkered pattern.